# Android Studio syntax highlighting red on Google Maps example project even though it's running fine

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, syntax

I followed the example project for the Google Maps SDK as found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker), and it works perfectly. However the syntax highlighting in the MapsMarkerActivity is mostly red as shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn4sY.png).

I'm curious as to why this is and how I'd go about fixing it.

On another note, the compiler also prints out the following warnings:

```
[![WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.

WARNING: Configuration 'androidTestCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'androidTestImplementation' and 'androidTestApi'.

WARNING: Configuration 'androidTestApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'androidTestImplementation'.

WARNING: Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation' and 'testApi'.

WARNING: Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.][2]][2]
```

Where would I find these outdated bits of code and what would be the best way to go about replacing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.For red underline, probably is a lint bug, try update android studio and gradle plugin to latest version. If still failed, disable the lint option as below image:

[image]

2 For these warning, just do as IDE prompts,for example,replace compile with implementation. the other warnings are same handled.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```